# Storing Multiple Values to a Single Key in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, ios7

In my application i am getting data from the server.i parsed the data and added to individual arrays. Here i am having 2 arrays.

For example

Array A : @"1",@"2",@"3",@"2",@"3",@"4",etc..
Array B : @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",etc..

Now i want to create a Dictionary with Array A as keys and Array B as Values.
i am trying to create Dictionary like this:

```
dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:B forKeys:A];
```

But it is giving only single value for a single Key. here how can i store multiple values for a single key.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that you have both `complete`... objects are arrays with the same number of elements? Show us how you create them.

Comment: Yes i am having Same Number of objects in Both Arrays.

Comment: No nulls in your arrays?

Comment: For Different keys its working. But my problem is Storing multiple values for single key.

Comment: Create an array and add the multiple objects in that array. You can store an array for a key by `setObject: forKey:` method. You can only set one value for a key.

Comment: Keys in NSDictionary must be unique.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr i am getting data from the server. data is dynamic we don't know how many multiple key values are there.

Comment: what you want for key on set the whole dictionary?

Comment: So before adding a key value pair in dictionary, check a value is exist for that key. If exist, add the new value and old value in an array and set that array as object for that key.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr can u please give me a example.

Comment: @iSuresh I've added a sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For Different keys its working. But my problem is Storing multiple values for single key.

You can't store multiple values for a single key directly -- dictionaries can only have one value per key. What you can do is store an array as the value. So, you could create a mutable dictionary and add the keys and values one at a time. Make the values all mutable arrays, and check for an existing value for the given key before setting it. If you find one, add the new value to the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Assuming `dataDict` is a `NSMutableDictionary` and initialised.

```
- (void)addValueInDataDict:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {

     if ([dataDict objectForKey:key] != nil) {
         //Already exist a value for the key
         id object = [dataDict objectForKey:key];
         NSMutableArray *objectArray;
         if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {

             objectArray = (NSMutableArray *)object;
         } else {

            NSMutableArray *objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         }
         [objectArray addObject:value];
         [dataDict setObject:objectArray forKey:key];
     } else {
         //No value for the key
         [dataDict setObject:value forKey:key];
     }
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but it might be easier to make every value in the dictionary an array, even if there's only one item for that key. The way you've got it now, anyone reading a value out of the dictionary will have to test the value to see if it's an array.

Comment: @Caleb Yes, you are right. So on using `dataDict` all values will be of same type.